# dep ensure removing the install folders

Tags: go, godeps

I have installed the httprouter package using the following command

```
dep ensure -add github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter

      vendor
        └── github.com
            ├── julienschmidt
            │   └── httprouter
```

Then I have installed the uuid package

```
dep ensure -add github.com/satori/go.uuid
  vendor
        └── github.com
            ├── satori
```

The julienschmidt router package gone away. Why dep is deleting the previous installation ?

Deleting the entry on Gopkg.lock

Gopkg.toml has this entry

```
[[constraint]]
  name = "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
  version = "1.1.0"

[[constraint]]
  name = "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
  version = "1.2.0"
```

Will this affect anything ?

My directory structure

```
gopath/src/github.com
- services
  - service-auth
  - service-signup
- vendor
   - github.com
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
"github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter" is not imported by your project, and has been temporarily added to Gopkg.lock and vendor/.
If you run "dep ensure" again before actually importing it, it will disappear from Gopkg.lock and vendor/.
```

If you just run `dep ensure -add {package}` without importing it in code. It will got remove in the next `dep ensure`

Comment: I am having the import on both packages. my vendor folder is directly under github.com folder of my local machine. Will that be a problem ?

Comment: It's highly suspicious

Comment: yes. I have changed the directory structure. Its worked.

Comment: You might consider open an issue in dep github. =]